# Issue on react-testing-library and Location/Path in header

Tags: reactjs, testing, react-testing-library

I have a header component as below and I am trying to write tests for it. I am getting error `inserts text in h2 >>> TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined`

header.js

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'

const Header = ({ title }) => {
const location = useLocation();  <<<< Error Occurs here

 return (
    <header className='header'>
       <h2 data-testid='h2HeaderTag'>{title}</h2>
       {location.pathname === '/'}
    </header>
 )}
```

Header.test.js :

```
it("inserts text in h2", () => {
   const { getByTestId, getByText } = render(<Header title="title" />);

   expect(getByTestId("h2HeaderTag")).toHaveTextContent("title");
   expect(getByText("title")).toHaveClass("fancy-h2");
});
```

Comment: What sort of router is the component being tested being rendered into?

Comment: Right understand , was a mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you are not rendering the component being tested into a router for it to have a routing context and defined location. You can provide a custom wrapper to wrap the component being tested that provides a routing context. See [Wrapper API](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api#wrapper).

1. Create a `RouterWrapper` test utility

   ```
   import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

   export const RouterWrapper = ({ children }) => (
     <MemoryRouter>{children}</MemoryRouter>
   );
   ```
2. Import and use the `RouterWrapper` in your test

   ```
   import { RouterWrapper } from '../path/to/test/utils';

   it("inserts text in h2", () => {
     const { getByTestId, getByText } = render(
       <Header title="title" />,
       { wrapper: RouterWrapper }
     );

     expect(getByTestId("h2HeaderTag")).toHaveTextContent("title");
     expect(getByText("title")).toHaveClass("fancy-h2");
   });
   ```